# How can i ignore \n Newline \r Carrige return by using the COPY within postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, curl, copy, tr

I want to copy a text data from a url. The text data has new lines and carrige returns. How can i ignore new line and carrige return within the copy command.

I tryed following options with curl and tr:

```
COPY "routing_import_gm" ("request") FROM PROGRAM 'curl "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=48.xxxxxx,+11.xxxxxx&destination=48.xxxxxx,+11.xxxxxx&departure_time=1637535600&key=**********" | tr -d ''\n'' ';
```

But SQL ERROR 38000 and ended withe kindprocess code 255. I think the problem is with ' within ''.
I use windows.

Comment: `....| tr -d "\n" ';`.   change the double-single-quotes to one double-quote (around the `\n`).  But maybe the prameter after PROGRAM needs to be surrounded by double-quotes too.

Comment: Last time I looked, Windows didn't have `curs` and `tr` installed by default. Please quote the complete error message.